# Use a DDL to select records in a gridview VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I've got a simple DDL with values like 1, 2, 3.

I have a Gridview with a BoundField DataField="Cycle"

I want to pick a value from the Drop Down List and I want to update my Gridview to only show the records where Cycle = the picked value.

I'm doing this instead of using a Textbox with a Submit button.

When I have my connection string setup, I can test the query and it works, I just can't get the selected/updated value of the drop down List to change the gridview.

Thanks,  Bill

Comment: My Drop Down List is Outside the Gridview.

Comment: you must set the AutoPostBack property of the DropDown to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the DDL aka ComboBox [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event. In that event query your DB fetching the data based on the SelectedItem value.

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction, I made a button, and on it's click event  I used the dropDownList1.SelectedValue.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I created the gridview before the DDL and that threw me off as the datasource was already setup. I ended up redefining the gridview connection  and had as it's control parameter the DDL. With that done when I select a new value the GridView refreshes the query.

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/FromHost06192012_11/FromHost.mdb" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE ([Cycle] = ?) ORDER BY [Route]">
        <SelectParameters>
           <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="**DropDownList1**" DefaultValue="%" Name="Cycle2" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```